# Add a new value to a field with a for loop, and keep the original value

Tags: python, for-loop, pandas

I gave this for loop a try.

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
import numpy as np

Input = pd.read_csv('C:/PyTemp/Input.csv')

Input = pd.DataFrame(Input)

print (Input)

AGE = Input['AGE']

QUALITY = Input['QUALITY']



for i in range(1,len(Input)):
    Input['DELTA'] = Input['QUALITY'] * .1
    Input.iloc[i]['QUALITY'] = Input.iloc[i-1]['QUALITY']+ Input.iloc['i']['DELTA']

print(Input)
```

My input dataframe:

```
    QUALITY AGE
0      15   10
0           11
0           12
```

The result I am trying to achieve:

```
    QUALITY AGE DELTA
0   15      10  1.5
0   16.5    11  1.65
0   18.15   12  1.815
```

This is the complete error:

```
TypeError: cannot do label indexing on <class 'pandas.core.index.Int64Index'> with these indexers [i] of <type 'str'>
```

I also tried this for loop. The final value is correct, but it overwrites the prior values

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
import numpy as np

Input = pd.read_csv('C:/PyTemp/Input.csv')

Input = pd.DataFrame(Input)

print (Input)

AGE = Input['AGE']

QUALITY = Input['QUALITY']


for i in range(1,len(Input)):
  Input['DELTA'] = Input['QUALITY'] * .1
  Input['QUALITY'] = Input['QUALITY'][i-1]+Input['DELTA']

print(Input)
```

Result:

```
   QUALITY  AGE  DELTA
0    18.15   10   1.65
1    18.15   11   1.65
2    18.15   12   1.65
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The for loop is not actually doing what you are thinking. This line `Input['DELTA'] = Input['QUALITY'] * .1` is actually assigning the *entire* column through each loop. You can achieve the result for that column by doing this outside of the for loop. You are receiving the error because `.iloc` only takes integers, not strings. `.loc` will work for you as long as your index is ordered and consecutive (0, 1, 2...)

```
for i in range(len(Input) -1):
    Input.loc[i+1, 'QUALITY'] = Input.loc[i, 'QUALITY'] + Input.loc[i, 'QUALITY'] *.1

Input['DELTA'] = Input['QUALITY'] *.1

Input
    QUALITY AGE DELTA
0   15.00   10  1.500
1   16.50   11  1.650
2   18.15   12  1.815
```

Note that I don't necessarily think this is the best way to achieve the result, however I am trying to address the original question about using a for loop to achieve the desired result.